# Abrir modal hecho con bootstrap con java MVC

Tags: javascript, java, bootstrap, mvc, modal

estoy haciendo una pagina con java MVC y Bootstrap. Tengo una vista que es un modal, y quiero llamarlo desde la clase  java controlador. Es decir en mi pagina principal, quiero apretar un boton y que me abra el modal que esta en otra pagina, esto para no hacer una sola web que cargue todo junto, supongo que no sería lo ideal. No estoy encontrando la forma de hacerlo.

Ejemplo de código:

modelEjemplo.html

```html
modalEjemplo.html

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Index.html

```html
<%@ include file="includes/head.jsp" %>
<body>

Pagina principal:
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEjemplo">Abrir modal</a>
<%@ include file="includes/navbar.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="includes/footer.jsp" %>      

</body>

</html>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias. Saludos

Comment: yo tengo exactamente la misma duda, pudiste solucionarlo?